# drbd with IPv4 fallback

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, drbd

I was setting up DRBD over IPv6, I want to ask if it is possible to provide both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in address section like below.

```
on server1 {
     disk /dev/sdb1;
     address 140.X.X.X:7788;
     address ipv6 [2001:7C0:1300:5908::98:111]:7788
} 
on server2 {
     disk /dev/sdb1;
     address 140.X.X.X:7788;
     address ipv6 [2001:7C0:1300:5908::98:110]:7788
}
```

If it is not possible, is there a way to fallback to IPv4 when IPv6 is not available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Only one address per host is considered a valid configuration by the parser.